# How to handle external barcode scanner enter suffix added to scanned string in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and I'm stuck trying to handle the scan in an Android smartphone that has a **physical** barcode scanner in it. 
It scans a barcode and returns a string like "S3XAHKBC" but with a suffix "\n".

So I'm **not** talking about a software camera driven barcode reader.

In an Android application written in Java I would do something like:

```java
myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT)) {
      submit();
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

In Flutter I've tried everything I found in the documentation and this is what I'd like to get working:

```dart
TextFormField(
  controller: barcodeStringController,
  autofocus: true,
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
  onFieldSubmitted: (v) => submit(),
);
```

Do anyone have experience with something like this?

Comment: Most physical barcode scanners give you a way to change the suffix.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what the issue it. Are you trying to do something when a newline char is entered into the text field (i.e. when you set the controller text from the scanner)?

Comment: @MarkRansom this is exactly what the barcode scanner already does.

Comment: @AlexMeuer yes, when a string is scanned a suffix "\n" is added and i need to submit the string

Comment: I should have been more specific: most barcode scanners will allow you to turn off the suffix or set it to an empty string.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, but I need the barcode scanner to perform an action when it ends scanning. This is the purpose of the suffix, to trigger an event when listened.
It's just that I can't find a way to listen to that suffix

Comment: The reason `\n` is a common suffix is that it should work the same as the Enter key on a physical keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that works but isn't really nice

```dart
TextFormField(
  controller: barcodeStringController,
  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
  autofocus: true,
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  maxLines: null,
  onFieldSubmitted: (value) => submit(), //to handle submit from keyboard
  validator: (value){
    //to handle submit from hardware barcode reader
    if(value.contains('\n') || value.contains('\t')){ 
      barcodeStringController.text = value.replaceAll('\n', '').replaceAll('\t', '');
      submit();
    }
    return null;
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Textfield onChanged event or  TextEditingController i guess .

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes

Comment: Already tried but I'm not able to notice when the suffix is added to the string

Comment: Maybe rawkeyboardlistener may help .https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RawKeyboardListener-class.html

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately, it's onKey is triggered by the physical buttons of the device only

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, I finally achieved the desired effect by listening to the TextField.onChanged method.

```html
TextField(
   keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
   // maxLines !=1, if maxLines==1 can't type '\n', and onChanged can't capture ‘\n’
   maxLines: null,
   autofocus: true,
   controller: state.ipController,
   focusNode: state.ipFocusNode,
   onChanged: (text) {
     print('onChanged : -$text-');
     if (text.endsWith('\n')) {
        // remove '\n'
        String filter = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
        // update 
        state.ipController.value = TextEditingValue(
             text: filter,
             selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: filter.length),
        );
        /// you can do something
        ......
     }
   },
 ),

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    return RawKeyboardListener(
      focusNode: state.keyboardFocusNode,
      onKey: (keyEvent) {
        // key down
        if (keyEvent.runtimeType.toString() == 'RawKeyDownEvent') {
          RawKeyEventDataAndroid key = keyEvent.data; 
          if (isOnScan(key.keyCode)) { 
            if (!state.ipFocusNode.hasFocus) {
              // focus
              state.ipFocusNode.requestFocus();
            }
            // clear text
            state.ipController.clear();
          }
        } else {
//         key up
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(……),
    );
  } 

//   second method :
  RawKeyboard.instance.addListener((RawKeyEvent keyEvent) {
  if (keyEvent.runtimeType.toString() == 'RawKeyDownEvent') {
    RawKeyEventDataAndroid key = keyEvent.data;
    if (ScanUtils.isOnScan(key.keyCode)) {
      if (!state.ipFocusNode.hasFocus) {
        state.ipFocusNode.requestFocus();
      }
      state.ipController.clear();
    }
  } else { }
});

// left scan keyCode
static final int LEFT_SCAN_KEY = 132;
// right scan keyCode
static final int RIGHT_SCAN_KEY = 133;
// scan keyCode
static final int SCAN_KEY = 165;
// bluetooth scan keyCode (i'm not test)
static final int SCAN_KEY = 113;
   
static bool isOnScan(int keyCode) {
  return keyCode == LEFT_SCAN_KEY ||
      keyCode == RIGHT_SCAN_KEY ||
      keyCode == SCAN_KEY ||
      keyCode == BLUETOOTH_SCAN_KEY;
}
```